# Python development - Storing results in a for loop

Tags: php, python, django

I am new to python and i am writing an XML file parser app. I have a directory full of XML files which i need to iterate through. Each file has attributes set such as 'HeadLine'. I am parsing the files with the code below

```
def index(request):
    dirlist = glob.glob("/home/somebody/vids/*.xml")
    for item in dirlist:
        newsML = ET.parse(item)
        NewsLines = newsML.getroot()
        HeadLine = NewsLines.getiterator("HeadLine")
```

What im not sure about is how to save the HeadLine element from each iteration of the loop. In PHP for example id just chuck it into a multidimensional array like;

```
$results[]['HeadLine']
```

What is the best way to deal with this in python? I am also using the Django framework if that helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to do this in Python is by appending to a list.

```
results = []
for item in dirlist:
  newsML = ET.parse(item)
  NewsLines = newsML.getroot()
  HeadLine = NewsLines.getiterator("HeadLine")
  results.append(HeadLine)
```

If you also want to extract all the elements out of the iterator as a list, then the last line would be `results.append(list(HeadLine))`.

Comment: Will this work well for returning the results in the template? I don't know how lists work but if in my code i have 'HeadLine' and 'Type' and 'Content' for example i want it to be easy to get these out together in my template. If you understand what im saying...

Comment: if you  have those different attributes you could create a dict like `data = {'headline': NewsLines.getiterator("HeadLine"), 'type': 'blah', 'content'}` and append that dictionary `results.append(data)`. So in your template you could Iterate over the results `{%for result in results %} {{ result.headline }} {{ endfor }}

Answer (score 1):

Since no other operations are performed in the loop, you can write it as follows:

```
results = [ET.parse(item).getroot().getiterator("HeadLine") for item in dirlist]
```

Comment: Thanks, i did consider this but as im learning i have writen it the long way just to make it easier for me to follow. Might refactor the code later.